# SQLAlchemy Mixins & MyPy: How to correctly type them?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, type-hinting, mypy, typing

I have the following situation: an SQLAlchemy base class `BaseModel`, and a collection of tables I want to represent, all of them having the `file` column.

In my DB there are also tables that do not have the `file` column, so I do not want to include it in my `BaseModel`. That's why I use a mixin.

```py
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import Mapped, declarative_base, declarative_mixin, declared_attr


class _BaseModel(object):

    @declared_attr
    def __tablename__(cls) -> Mapped[str]:
        return cls.__name__.lower()

    id: int = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)


@declarative_mixin
class WithFile:
    """Extraction table mixin."""

    @declared_attr
    def file(cls) -> Mapped[int]:
        """File name."""
        return Column(String)


BaseModel = declarative_base(cls=_BaseModel)
```

Now i can represent a table with the file attribute as:

```py
class MyTable(WithFile, BaseModel):

    some_other_column: Column(String)
```

Now, let's say I want to define a function that queries any of the tables for the records from a given file:

```py
from typing import List, Type, TypeVar
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

T = TypeVar("T")


def file_query(db: Session, model: Type[T], file: str) -> List[T]:
    return db.query(model).filter(model.file == file).all()
```

The question is, how should I correctly type the `model` argument, to have all the properties of an SQLAlchemy ORM and also the `file` attribute?

To make it clearer, the operation I'd need is the `Intersection` proposed in [PEP 483](https://peps.python.org/pep-0483/#fundamental-building-blocks), which I'm afraid it was never implemented.

Take into account that I cannot create an "intermediate class just for typing" since by doing so I would be registering it as a model mapping an unnecessary and non-existing DB table.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You actually can 'create an "intermediate class just for typing"'. Guard it `if typing.TYPE_CHECKING:` and use string annotations and/or `annotations` future to avoid NameError's. It is `False` at runtime, but visible for typecheckers - this is the main reason why `TYPE_CHECKING` exists.